# AWS elasticache redis cluster online resize when cluster mode is disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

What happens when you resize a redis cluster with cluster mode disabled and multiple read replicas.

Does it roll each instance one by one? Is it an online operation? Having difficulty finding documentation to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while trying to resize the cluster there is a clear message indicating that "For non-clustered Redis, you may notice a brief interruption of a few seconds on the primary node".